# How can I add a custom programing language to NotepadQQ?

Tags: notepadqq

In NotepadQQ, I would like to add G-code and M-code programing language definitions/syntax. Is this possible for a user to do this? How is it done? I found a post about how to add a language 
https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/164
but it is a bit beyond my knowledge base.  Here is the gist of the post:

> It's not possible to migrate XMLs from Notepad++ to Notepadqq. They're
>   completely different formats. The best way is to write it from
>   scratch.
>
> [This is the CodeMirror documentation for writing modes (aka syntax
>   highlighters)](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi)
>
> [And this is an example of a syntax highlighter for makefiles written
>   by a Notepadqq contributor](https://github.com/notepadqq/CodeMirror/blob/5.3.0-nqq/mode/makefile/makefile.js)

It seems some knowledge of a formating language is needed to create such a makefile.  And I don't see how to implement it into notepadqq on my computer.

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry, but I don't think this is specifically an Ubuntu question. It might be better to put it on stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: @rplaughlin, I wasn't sure where to post it and I had found NPQQ posts here.  Actually, Askubuntu has 51 NPQQ posts to Stack Exchange's 9.  I do understand that Ask Ubuntu is "for Ubuntu-related questions".  And, I checked on Stack Overflow and questions about, "software tools commonly used by programmers," is in their bailiwick. So, I'll post over there.  Can I delete this question then?

Comment: @rplaughlin:  Askubuntu has a tag for notepadqq while stackoverflow doesn't.

Comment: @HolyHarmonica The question is on-topic, so don't worry. You're welcome to leave it as is.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm glad you were able to investigate that further.